# Full-hight div breaks with Unslider slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, unslider

I'm trying to put together a very simple horizontal slideshow using the Unslidr plugin, which I've chosen due to its small size and easy markup.

I'm running into a problem in that, while the slides and transitions work just fine, I'm only seeing a sliver of the background images behind the text on that slide, rather than the whole screen.

I assume this is a conflict in the way I'm making the images fullscreen with how Unslider works, but I can't figure out a way around it – any help is much appreciated

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4aAGP/2/

**The html:**

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="prev">

    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">Previous slide</a>

</div>

<div class="next">

    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">Next slide</a>

</div>

<div class="banner">

    <ul>

    <li>

    <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/05.jpg);">TEST 02</div>

            </li>

            <li>

            <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/02.jpg);">TEST 03</div>

            </li>

        <li>

        <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/03.jpg);">TEST 04</div>

        </li>

        <li>

        <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/04.jpg);">TEST 05</div>

        </li>

        <li>

        <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/05.jpg);">TEST 06</div>

        </li>

        <li>

        <div class="slider" style="background: url(img/06.jpg);">TEST 07</div>

        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
body {color: red; min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.wrapper {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.prev {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
left: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
z-index: 600;
}

.next {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
right: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
z-index: 600;
}


.banner { 
position: relative; 
overflow: auto; 
min-height: 100%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;

    }

.banner li { 
list-style: none; 
position: relative;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 100%;

}

    .banner ul li { 
    float: left; 
min-height: 100%;
    }


.slider {
position: relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;top: 0;left: 0; no-repeat center center;display: block; -webkit-box;-moz-background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;-webkit-box-pack: center;-webkit-box-align: center; }
```

Comment: Maybe creating a fiddle with appropriate libraries embedded would really help.

Comment: Where did you even linked that library. Choose jquery under Frameworks and Extensions on left side too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4aAGP/2/

updated that fiddle, sorry, brain meltdown on my part

Comment: Try adding "padding-top: 100%;" at the end of your slider class attributes in your CSS. I've tested only in chrome but it's a working hack on my end. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: That's helped, but has introduced a new problem not visible on the fiddle – I've uploaded it to my webspace, problem is there in Chrome and Safari

http://slides.alexanderecob.com/

1. The images are coming in really big – they're supposed to be matching the width of the window but they're far bigger than that.

2. The text on the first slide is invisible for some reason

3. When the text is visible on the subsequent slides, it's below the slide image, and causes a repeat of the image beneath the one that's already there

Comment: Okay, have solved the image repeat and text issue by making an absolutely positioned div for the text within the slide – only issue now is the images coming in much larger than they should do